# Ansible: Selecting a nested value with json_query

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to verify a couple of service endpoints via a REST API and ansbile's uri module

```
    - name: Wait until service is fully deployed
      local_action:
        module: uri
        url: http://somerestserver/{{ app_name }}-{{ item }}/tasks
        methon: GET
      register: response
      loop: "{{ range(0, instances) | list }}"
```

The response varialbe looks something like this:

```
"response": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "item": 0,
                "json": {
                    "tasks": [
                        {
                            "appId": "node-0",
                            "healthCheckResults": [
                                {
                                    "alive": true,
                                    ...
                                }
                            ],
                            ...
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "msg": "OK (674 bytes)",
            },
            {
                "item": 1,
                "json": {
                    "tasks": [
                        {
                            "appId": "node-1",
                            "healthCheckResults": [
                                {
                                    "alive": true,
                                    ...
                                }
                            ],
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "msg": "OK (674 bytes)",
            },
            {
                "item": 2,
                "json": {
                    "tasks": [
                        {
                            "appId": "node-2",
                            "healthCheckResults": [
                                {
                                    "alive": true,
                                    ...
                                }
                            ],
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "msg": "OK (674 bytes)",
            }
        ]
    }
```

What I'd like to do now is to wait until all my services report `alive: true`

```
    - name: Wait until service is fully deployed
      local_action:
        module: uri
        url: http://somerestserver/{{ app_name }}-{{ item }}/tasks
        methon: GET
      register: response
      loop: "{{ range(0, instances) | list }}"
      until: <All services report alive>
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I tried

```
until: response | json_query('results[*].json.tasks[*].healthCheckResults[*].alive') == [true]*instances
```

which unfortunately doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, today I learned that can combine `loop` and `until` on a single task, which was a surprise. So that's cool.

In any case, you are so close to a solution.  Given your input data, your query will result in something like:

```
[
  [
    [
      true
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      true
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      true
    ]
  ]
]
```

That's never going to match the `[true, true, true]` list to which you're comparing it.  You just need to apply a couple jmespath [flatten](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#flatten-operator) operators, like this:

```
results[*].json.tasks[*].healthCheckResults[*].alive[][]
```

Given you sample input, that results in:

```
[true, true, true]
```

In your playbook, that would be:

```
- name: Wait until service is fully deployed
  local_action:
    module: uri
    url: http://somerestserver/{{ app_name }}-{{ item }}/tasks
    methon: GET
  register: response
  loop: "{{ range(0, instances) | list }}"
  until: response|json_query('results[*].json.tasks[*].healthCheckResults[*].alive[][]') == [true]*instances
```

In the future, you can try out your queries by pasting your data into the text box at http://jmespath.org/ and then typing your queries above it.

Comment: Almost... The content of the variable looks different while iterating (compared to after the iteration): https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop
So `until: response | json_query('json.tasks[*].healthCheckResults[*].alive[]') == [true]` works now. Thanks a bunch!